# Nested Redux persistor

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-persist

I have a Redux store with this structure:

```
{ui: {
    drawer: false,
    dialog: false
    },
other_0: {
    other_0_0: false,
    other_0_1: 'and'
    },
other_1: {
    other_1_0: null,
    other_1_1: true
    }
}
```

**I'd like to persist only the key drawer.**

My code so far:

```js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import other_0_reducer from "./other_0_reducer";
import other_1_reducer from "./other_1_reducer";
import ui_reducer from "./ui_reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  other_0: other_0_reducer,
  other_1: other_1_reducer,
  ui: ui_reducer,
});

const pConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ["ui"]
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(pConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(pReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

**This keeps alive the parent key "ui" but in reality I'd like to blacklist the child "dialog".**

It's basically a nested persistor: I looked at other articles on StackOverflow but I can't make it work. Can someone help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist each reducer separately.

```js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import other_0_reducer from "./other_0_reducer";
import other_1_reducer from "./other_1_reducer";
import ui_reducer from "./ui_reducer";

const uiPersistConfig = {
  key: "ui",
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ["drawer"]
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  other_0: other_0_reducer,
  other_1: other_1_reducer,
  ui: persistReducer(uiPersistConfig, ui_reducer)
});

const pConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: []
};

const pReducer = persistReducer(pConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(pReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

Hope this helps.